# Acumatica: Procedure to rename a table in SQL without breaking screens, etc

Tags: acumatica

I have a couple of custom tables I created and a few screens, imports, etc. based on them.  Then realized I didn't prefix with our own 2 character tenant.  Seemed like a simple refactor but If I rename SQL tables and the DAC classes (I'm using extension library) then my ASPX/Screen editor is broken (did not rename Graphs or Graph views) Tried to modify ASPX markup and reload changed files but then I wound up with an empty screen in screen editor.  I'm putting everything back and restoring from previous day package export for now. Any tips/tricks for renaming SQL/DAC classes.  I looked at PXTableName attribute (to try to keep code the same and only change SQL tables) but could not understand why that requires another virtual/abstract class.

Update: Tried again and this time no problems just renaming DAC and SQL table.  Not sure what mistake I made the first time.

Comment: I have done this a few times.  The easiest thing for me is to edit the Project XML and then use Find and Replace to edit all the aspx page files, and edit the DAC's (and their filenames).  It isn't "simple" but it isn't too difficult.  Just get a full backup of your customization project, your Visual Studio project, and take a snapshot of your instance in case you completely blow it the first try.  It's much easier to try again from a fresh restore than to try to figure out what you broke if you miss something.  Looking forward to see if someone posts something better as an answer!  Good luck!

Comment: Apparently, I blew it on the first try somehow. I just tried renaming DAC and SQL table again and it just worked and my screens, imports, etc. all continue to work because they talk to the graph/views, not directly to the DAC.

Comment: Sounds good. Remember to remove your old DAC names from the project (Database Scripts) and add the new DAC names so that the new tables are included in the project instead of the old DAC names.